# How to fix Undefined index:

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined index: id_desafilter in D:\Sofwares\XAMPP
>   7.5.5.0\htdocs\project2\views\filterdata.php on line 45
>
> Notice: Undefined index: status_krlfilter in D:\Sofwares\XAMPP
>   7.5.5.0\htdocs\project2\views\filterdata.php on line 46

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: show your code from where and you get id_desafilter

Comment: no code - no chance of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

that means that your variable may not be defined.

Use **[isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)** function.

You should wrap it into a condition like this :

```
if(!isset($id_desafilter)){
  $id_desafilter = "WHAT_YOU_WANT";
}
else{
 $id_desafilter = "WHAT_YOU_WANT";
}
```

This is how you can make sure your variable is define.

> But please make sure to join your code to be helped

Have Fun :)